# Java package-private access modifier behavior in case of package collision

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Let's say, I am using a 3rd party jar `A.jar` in my project, with some members (classes, methods etc.) with default access (package private). Now, if I create the same package name in my project, I am able to access the members with default access modifier from A.jar (I tried this with Java Projects in Eclipse).

[Oracle's document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) says:

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package

Isn't this philosophy violated in this particular use case(that too without using reflection), given that it is not what the developer of `A.jar` would have intended, as she would have wanted only classes in her package to access this particular member?

Also does it mean, that package-private is a convenience mechanism, but can't be used for securing the data etc.?

Comment: In the presence of reflection, no scoping modifies can "be used for securing the data."  Modifiers like public and private are an organizational tool, not a security mechanism.

Comment: Yes I understand that, anyhow reflection will be disabled in SecurityManager. But my question stands in the absence of reflection, when I want to secure something to be accessible only in my package. Sorry for confusion there.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't this philosophy violated in this particular use case(that too without using reflection), given that it is not what the developer of A.jar would have intended, as she would have wanted only classes in her package to access this particular member?

If she  used default access modifier she would have less interested in securing her default members.